# Reqwest: read body text and return reqwest::Error

Tags: rust, reqwest

I want to use reqwest to make a request, then print the response's body and return a reqwest::Error if the status code was >= 400. This is how I would like to do this:

```rust
pub async fn print_body() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").await?;
    println!("received text: {:?}", response.text().await?);
    response.error_for_status()?;
    Ok(())
```

The trouble is that both `response.text()` and `response.error_for_status()` consume the response. Debug printing the response itself or the error from `response.error_for_status()` does not print the response body.

I've tried saving the status code, then generating a reqwest::Error if the status code is >= 400, but reqwest::Error is not meant to be constructed by library users since its `inner` field and constructor are private. Ideally a reqwest::Error is returned since other functions depend on this API, and I would like to understand if it's possible to achieve this without changing the public interface.

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eadb635bafe258198ee691473b09b7c3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have glossed over the [`error_for_status_ref()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.error_for_status_ref) method, which does not consume the response.  You just need to swap the order of the calls:

```
pub async fn print_body() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").await?;
    response.error_for_status_ref()?;
    println!("received text: {:?}", response.text().await?);
    Ok(())
}
```

To print the text regardless, just store the result of `error_for_status_ref()` and map the reference in the `Ok` case to be `()` to match the return type of your function:

```
pub async fn print_body() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").await?;
    let result = response.error_for_status_ref().map(|_| ());
    println!("received text: {:?}", response.text().await?);
    result
}
```

Comment: TIL about using `.map()` on results. Thank you @cdhowie for the very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue if you handle your error case before you retreive the text as `error_for_status` returns the `Response` if everything is ok:

```rust
pub async fn print_body() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").await?;
    println!("received text: {:?}", response.error_for_status()?.text().await?);
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @cafce25 for pointing me back to `error_for_status_ref`, which I originally passed over since it returns a reference to self on Ok(), giving me compiler errors if I tried to keep the full result to use after calling `.text()`. But grabbing just the error with `.err()` resolves it:

```rust
pub async fn print_body() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::get("https://www.rust-lang.org").await?;
    let maybe_err = response.error_for_status_ref().err();
    println!("received text: {:?}", response.text().await?);
    match maybe_err {
        Some(e) => Err(e),
        None => Ok(()),
    }
}
```